# Foreign key not shown with Many to Many Relationship in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a two simple models like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100) #Id is automatically generated by Django
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

class File(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

With the rule of database, bridge entity(table) is created. What I want to know is while inserting the data I want to insert the database with the session_id(foreign key) in my case so that I can retrieve later for my use. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to add a field to the intermediary (joining) table?

Comment: What is this `session_id` you want to use? Is it to link the `User` with the `File`? If so, this is not required as you can follow relationships backwards/forwards in django ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your trying to add data to ManyToMany Relationships, you'll have to define the joining table using the `through` option. [Read here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) for more information.

Note, however, you shouldn't be saving the session ID - what are you trying to achieve? The reason for this is a user won't always have the same sessionID and the data associated with the session (ie, request.session[*]) may be deleted.

In any case, an example would look something like this

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100) #Id is automatically generated by Django
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

class File(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='UserFile')
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class UserFile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file = models.ForeignKey(File)
    # Should probably use CharField if you know the length
    session_id = models.TextField()
```

Comment: I want to insert session_id into database too so that I can retrieve the data from database according to that session_id.

Comment: I've added an example, but unless you have good reason you may wish to reconsider using the sessionid

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't wanted to save to session_id. I just want to get the session_id once the user logs in. How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you need the session_id? Under normal circumstances you can just use the `request.session` object transparently.

Comment: To make the logout. Would a = request.session would do?

Comment: files' is a manually-defined m2m relation through model UserShare, which does not have foreign keys to File and Share

Comment: If your using `django.contrib.auth`, `from django.contrib.auth import logout` then `logout(request)`. If you've rolled your own auth it will vary, but generally involves removing the session information like so: `request.session.flush()`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22367/discussion-between-danielb-and-user1881957)

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood from your question, you may want to refer Foreign Key Section of the documentation.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/

e.g:
manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer')